# Flutter: How to remove empty space at the top of ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a `ListView` without any `padding` or `margin`. But the `ListView` was separated with empty space like this one:

[image]

And this is my code of this `ListView`:

```dart
content: Container(
  width: context.widthPct(.5),
  height: context.heightPct(.4),
  child: CupertinoScrollbar(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Image.asset("assets/logo_horizontal.png"),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Text(
            "Sumber data doa :\nApa Doanya app\n\nTerima kasih sudah\nmenggunakan Moodo :D\n\n nabilrei \n hantsnm \n rennyatikas \n cayne.dameron \n",
            style: Style().body,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "versi 1.0.0",
            style: Style(styleColor: Colors.grey.shade600).body,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

So, how can I remove empty space at the top of this ListView?

Comment: By default the listview has a padding, set the listview padding to zero.

Comment: Oh yes, i found the answer here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842 . Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: ListView
```

Answer (score 21):

Listview has default padding, you can change it by specifying your required EdgeInsets. To remove padding use `EdgeInsets.zero`

```
ListView(
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
children: [],
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set padding to zero

```
ListView(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.zero,
   itemBuilder: ...,
   itemCount: ...
);
```

Or control padding in listview

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
  itemBuilder: ...,
  itemCount: ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(
            'Job Type',
          );
        },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

MediaQuery.removePadding(
context: context,
removeTop: true,
child: ListView

It will work for builder also

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).